# How to delete text autofill on firefox?

Tags: mac, firefox

I am clicking on a text input and there are saved searches.

How can I delete those saved searches?

I'm on firefox and mac. I've tried cmd clicking and that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the three vertical bars looking button, then click Library > History > Clear recent history and then in the dialog box uncheck everything except "Form and search history" and then set the Time range to Everything or what you like , click OK to remove all address bar history.

Will work on Windows/Linux/MacOS. Hope that helps

[image]